# Concise syntax for partial in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pointfree, partial-application

Learning Haskell some time ago, I felt in love with pointfree notation and especially convenient partial function application - just supply args you know. In Clojure, I have `partial` all the time. I think having a special syntax for partial in reader will be nice to have.

Look at the sample code:

```
; Notation with points:
(map (+ 10 (* % 2)) [1 2 3])

; With partial:
(map (comp (partial + 10) (partial * 2)) [1 2 3])

; Let #[] syntax means partial application in reader:
(map (comp #[+ 10] #[* 2]) [1 2 3])
```

This is so nice! Is there something like this? Is there possibility to define custom reader macro?

Comment: *Pointfree notation :) Pointless notation has a different meaning

Comment: @demi: you should try to edit your question and make it a little more objective, and a little less about "nice" and "good". I find your question interesting (since I know little about Clojure, but I know it lacks read macros, which is the way something like that would be written in Common Lisp, for example), but it is too opinionated. At the moment I'm writing this, there are already 2 votes for closing it, so be warned.

Comment: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1760

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An anonymous function syntax #(...) can be used similarly to what you are trying to do:

```
user=> (map (comp (partial + 10) (partial * 2)) [1 2 3])
(12 14 16)
```

is equivalent to:

```
user=> (map (comp #(+ 10 %) #(* 2 %)) [1 2 3])
(12 14 16)
```

A tiny little difference is `%` which just means a function argument, in this case the first and only.

Comment: The difference isn't so tiny if there are several arguments. Or if their number changes during development.

Comment: this is true. the above is just to illustrate a single argument functions. to "play" with the real (apply .. %&), [here](http://fulldisclojure.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-write-clojure-reader-macro-part.html) is a dangerous example of tweaking Clojure [code], whereas [here](https://gist.github.com/liquidz/919875) is a more gentle one [macro].

Comment: @tolitius Oh wow! This link to Disclojure is what I need. I'm very proud that Sean decided to have same syntax I proposed.

Comment: @demi isn't it a bit of an overkill. If your objective is to have something more concise, why not just define macro, let's say `$` that expands to `partial`? Then you can write `($ + a b ...)` so using the macro nets only 3 characters, just like the one you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I really like your idea for a partial function notation using the #[ ] literal.
Unfortunately, Clojure does not let us enhance the #() notation directly, but we can define ourselves a macro like `#p` for a partial application.

Given you have a function

```
(defn partial-wrap
  [args]
  (concat '(partial) args))
```

defined in `myapp.core`.
You can add the following entry into the `data_readers.clj` at the top of your classpath:

```
{p myapp.core/partial-wrap}
```

(usually one should use a namespace qualified symbol here like `a/p`, since unqualified symbols are reserved for Clojure. Nevertheless unqualified symbols do work, you need to rely on Clojure not overwriting them in a future version).

This finally allows to do almost what you asked for:

```
(map (comp #p[+ 10] #p[* 2]) [1 2 3])
=> (12 14 16)
```

Comment: while it does have a couple of disadvantages (no namespaced "p" and "#p[" is "read stumbling"), it is really cool to demonstrate the usage of `data_readers.clj`.

Comment: It would be great if there were shorthand notations for both partial and comp. E. g. #[] for comp like #[inc second vector] and maybe ~[] for partial, so that one could do #[~[+ 10] ~[* 2]]. My codebase is full of place-stealing partials.

Comment: main thing with "enhancing" the reader would be not to get over to the dark side with these `def compose[G[_]](implicit G0: Foldable[G]): Foldable[({type λ[α] = F[G[α]]})#λ]...` :)

Answer (score 2):

I found an approach to have partial in cases like in my question: `(map #(+ 10 (* 2 %)) [1 2 3)`. Use `->>` macro: `(map #(->> % (* 2) (+ 10)) [1 2 3]`. Similar macros are `->`, `..` and `doto` applicable in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you write code in vim, place the following code in your equivalent of `~/.vim/after/syntax/clojure.vim`, and turn conceal on by setting `conceallevel` to 2:

```
syntax keyword clojureFunc partial conceal cchar=$
```

This shortens `partial` on screen for the reader and writer but doesn’t make a mess of things for others.

I use this trick for making shorthand notations in most languages (e.g., the anonymous function keyword—fn, lambda, whatever—is concealed to the greek letter lambda in many languages).